# Xamarin Forms: Facing weird issues after installing the Xamarin.CommunityToolkit

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.communitytoolkit

Recently I have installed `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit (Version: 1.3.1)` for implementing the `BadgeView`. Also updated the `Xamarin.Forms (Version: 5.0.0.2291)` to the latest version. After that, I am facing some weird issues on my project. After the login the app is not opening the home page, scroll view is not working, collectionview scroll is not working, even some icon taps are also not firing.

All these features are working fine before installing `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit`. I have only installed `CommunityToolkit` and `XF` latest version. Are there any other packages or initialization required for the proper working of `CommunityToolkit`?

**Other Nuget Packages in the Project**

```
<PackageReference Include="Acr.UserDialogs" Version="7.1.0.446" />
<PackageReference Include="DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView" Version="2.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.16" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl" Version="1.1.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" Version="1.0.21" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http" Version="2.2.29" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="PCLStorage" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Plugin.MediaManager" Version="1.0.9" />
<PackageReference Include="Plugin.MediaManager.Forms" Version="0.8.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Rg.Plugins.Popup" Version="1.1.5.180" />
<PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp" Version="1.68.1-rc.147" />
<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.6.292" />
<PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfListView" Version="17.3.0.30" />
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" Version="3.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.HtmlLabel" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.LatestVersion" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media" Version="4.0.1.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer" Version="1.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle" Version="3.0.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.5.3.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading" Version="2.4.11.982" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms" Version="2.4.11.982" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg" Version="2.4.11.982" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms" Version="2.4.11.982" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Transformations" Version="2.4.11.982" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.8.0.1269" />
<PackageReference Include="XamForms.Enhanced.Calendar" Version="1.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker" Version="2.1.34" />
```

Which package has compatibility issue with Xamarin.CommunityToolkit?

**Update**

I found that the issue is happening when I set the text value for badgeview from xaml.cs file after an API call. When I comment that part there is no issue. My issues are entire page scrollview is not working, collectionview is not working, text on badgeview is not working also app is very slow.
Sample project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B2bGcCxqJWmoU5tLLbNwUaW04mjAJm4S/view?usp=sharing
There is a function `GetUserMedals()` in `HomePage1`, I am setting badgeview text on that function. For reproducing this issue I need to add some private APIs into the demo. Please don't post it anywhere.

Comment: Try to downgrade to 1.3.0. If it doesn't solve your issue there is another package in your project that has compatibility issues with Community Toolkit, because I am running almost the same setup currently.

Comment: @Adlorem Downgraded to 1.3.0, but no change. Could you tell which package has compatibility issue? how you fix your issue?

Comment: I think they mean that they (and most people) don’t have this issue. There is something specific to your setup. First, lets make sure your project is in a clean state: quit VS, delete all bin and obj folders in solution. Build again. Same problem? If so, Second, remove XCToolkit (and comment out all stuff that refers to it). Build. Good? If so, unfortunately you’ll have to remove nugets one at a time, to find the conflict. Yes, a lot of effort. Then look for alternative version of that nuget.

Comment: IF after removing XCToolkit, you still have problems, then it has nothing to do with XCT. Something else doesn’t work well with updated XF. In that case, add to question list of all nugets you use.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I removed the XCT and everything is working fine now.

Comment: To be sure it really is the cause, add it in again. Don’t use any feature of it yet - just add the nuget.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I found that the issue is happening when I set the text value for badgeview from xaml.cs file after an API call. When I comment that part there is no issue. My issues are entire page scrollview is not working, collectionview is not working, text on badgeview is not working also app is very slow.
Sample project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B2bGcCxqJWmoU5tLLbNwUaW04mjAJm4S/view?usp=sharing
There is a function `GetUserMedals()` in `HomePage1`, I am setting badgeview text on that function. Could you please have a look at the sample project?

Comment: Did you update xamarin forms from `v4.8.0.1269` to `v5.0.0.2291` just like that? You sure have a lot of breaking changes, please check [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/671052/xamarin-forms-facing-weird-issues-after-installing.html?childToView=677977#comment-677977

Comment: @FabriBertani https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/671052/xamarin-forms-facing-weird-issues-after-installing.html?childToView=677977#comment-677977

Comment: The issues happened when we tried to set 2 digit text for badge view. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a perfect solution from my [Microsoft thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/671052/xamarin-forms-facing-weird-issues-after-installing.html?childToView=678998#answer-678998).

Write a new badgeview.

Firstly, create CircleView.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class CircleView : BoxView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(double), typeof(CircleView), 0.0);
        public double CornerRadius
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
        }
        public CircleView()
        {
           // InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Then create contentview called `BadgeView.xaml` and edit it to the Grid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid      xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"     
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:MyProject"
           x:Class="MyProject.BadgeView"     
           HeightRequest="30"     
           WidthRequest="30">
    <local1:CircleView x:Name="BadgeCircle" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" CornerRadius="30" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="BadgeLabel" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is BadgeView.xaml.cs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
namespace MyProject
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class BadgeView : Grid
    {
        public static BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(BadgeView), "0", propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) =>
        {
            var view = (BadgeView)bindable;
            view.BadgeLabel.Text = (string)newVal;
        });
        public static BindableProperty BadgeColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create("BadgeColor", typeof(Color), typeof(BadgeView), Color.Blue, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) =>
        {
            var view = (BadgeView)bindable;
            view.BadgeCircle.BackgroundColor = (Color)newVal;
        });
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public Color BadgeColor
        {
            get
            {
                return (Color)GetValue(BadgeColorProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(BadgeColorProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public BadgeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BadgeLabel.Text = Text;
            BadgeCircle.BackgroundColor = BadgeColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to create a custom renderer for this CircleView in android.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MyProject;
using MyProject.Droid;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CircleView), typeof(CircleViewRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.Droid
{
    public class CircleViewRenderer : BoxRenderer
    {
        private float _cornerRadius;
        private RectF _bounds;
        private Path _path;
        public CircleViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var element = (CircleView)Element;
            _cornerRadius = TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)element.CornerRadius, Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
        }
        protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
        {
            base.OnSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            if (w != oldw && h != oldh)
            {
                _bounds = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
            }
            _path = new Path();
            _path.Reset();
            _path.AddRoundRect(_bounds, _cornerRadius, _cornerRadius, Path.Direction.Cw);
            _path.Close();
        }
        public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            canvas.Save();
            canvas.ClipPath(_path);
            base.Draw(canvas);
            canvas.Restore();
        }
    }
}
```

For iOS renderer.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CircleView), typeof(CircleViewRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS
{
    public class CircleViewRenderer : BoxRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
 
            if (Element == null)
                return;
 
            Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            Layer.CornerRadius = (float)((CircleView)Element).CornerRadius / 2.0f;
        }
 
    }
}
```

In the end, we can use it in your HomePage1.cs Find the  tag copy following code

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="34*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackLayout   Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid TranslationY="-15">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image 
                        Grid.Row="0" 
                        Source="ic_white_dot_xx.png">
                        <Image.HeightRequest>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>120</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>240</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>120</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </Image.HeightRequest>
                            <Image.WidthRequest>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>120</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>240</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>120</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </Image.WidthRequest>
                        </Image>
                    <Image 
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Source="ic_medal_xx.png" >
                        <Image.WidthRequest>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>60</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>90</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>60</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </Image.WidthRequest>
                            <Image.HeightRequest>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>60</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>90</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>60</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </Image.HeightRequest>
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
             <views:BadgeView    x:Name="medals_badge" Text="30" BadgeColor="Red" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid   TranslationY="-15">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Source="ic_white_dot_xx.png">
                        <Image.HeightRequest>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>120</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>240</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>120</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </Image.HeightRequest>
                        <Image.WidthRequest>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>120</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>240</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>120</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </Image.WidthRequest>
                    </Image>
                    <Image 
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Source="ic_badge_xx.png" >
                        <Image.WidthRequest>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>60</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>90</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>60</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </Image.WidthRequest>
                        <Image.HeightRequest>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>60</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>90</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>60</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </Image.HeightRequest>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
                <views:BadgeView    x:Name="badges_badge"   Text="30" BadgeColor="Red" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="2">
     <Grid>
        <Grid  TranslationY="-15">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image 
                Grid.Row="0" 
                Source="ic_white_dot_xx.png">
                <Image.HeightRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>120</OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>240</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>120</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                    </OnIdiom>
                </Image.HeightRequest>
                <Image.WidthRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>120</OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>240</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>120</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                    </OnIdiom>
                </Image.WidthRequest>
            </Image>
            <Image 
              HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Source="ic_star_xx.png" >
                <Image.WidthRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>60</OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>90</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>60</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                    </OnIdiom>
                </Image.WidthRequest>
                <Image.HeightRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>60</OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>90</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>60</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                    </OnIdiom>
                </Image.HeightRequest>
            </Image>
           </Grid>
        <views:BadgeView   x:Name="star_badge"   Text="30" BadgeColor="Red" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
       </Grid>
     </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

In the end, open your layout background code, you can find the GetUserMedals method. Set it directly.

```
medals_badge.Text = urlDetails.medals;
badges_badge.Text = urlDetails.badges;
star_badge.Text = urlDetails.stars;
```